# gnu screen - how to highlight searched text

Tags: gnu-screen

While doing a reverse text search via " C-a[? search_string",
I have to keep  pressing 'n' to figure out
occurrences of 'search_string'.

Is there a configuration in GNU screen that can hihglight searched text,
something similar to vim's ":set hlsearch" ?

Comment: No, doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there's no such option in screen, because it only searches for the next occurence but not for every occurence of your search string.